# How to call an instance method on a fragment class?

Tags: android

I have a fragment `Movies` that adapts a database to a list view. One of the helper method of this fragment class is `swapCursor`

```
public void swapCursor(final DatabaseAdapter myAdapter, final Cursor cursor){
    // Swap the cursor on the UI thread (prevents error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views)
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    });
}
```

I need to be able to access the `swapCursor` method from outside `Movies` class. I can't make `swapCursor` static becuase I would not be able to call `getActivity`.

How can I access `swapCursor`? Do I need to get an instance of my fragment class and call `swapCursor` as an instance method? How do I do that?

**edit**

I want to call `swapCursor`from another class that is neither a fragment nor an activity class, just a plain Java class. The class I am calling this method from is a singleton cursor manger class.

**edit**

Here is my entire `Movies` class to make things clearer

```
public class Movies extends Fragment {

    static DatabaseAdapter myAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
        myAdapter =  new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);

        DatabaseHelper dbh = DatabaseHelper.getInstanceOf(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT 0 _id, * FROM Movies ORDER BY CAST(imdbVotes AS int) DESC";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        swapCursor(myAdapter, cursor);

        ListView listView = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMovies);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void swapCursor(final DatabaseAdapter myAdapter, final Cursor cursor){
        // Swap the cursor on the UI thread (prevents error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views)
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "outside Fragment class" from where? from Activity or another Fragment?

Comment: make it static and add `Context` or `Activity` as one more method parameter.

Comment: @RohitArya From another class entirely (not activity or fragment)

Comment: @the_prole fragment is attached to the activity. Where is the adapter used? in Fragment ?

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, it is used in `Fragment` ... I would have to make the adapter variable a global variable so I can call `swapCursor` from outside the `Fragment` class.

Comment: @the_prole is this another class called from fragment or activity. Have some callback mechanism and call the method in fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using adapter for fragment (i.e view pager, tab adapter) // Fragment Activity always pre loads +2 of current fragment position.

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) pager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(pager, globalPosition);

    if (((FragmentDetail) fragment).getView() != null) {
                                   ((FragmentDetail) fragment).myMethod();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding two static global variables to my fragment class

```
static DatabaseAdapter myAdapter = null;
static Activity activity = null;
```

In my `onCreateView` view method I added the following line

```
activity = getActivity();
```

Then I made `swapCursor` static and removed `myAdapter` parameter

```
public static void swapCursor(final Cursor cursor){
    // Swap the cursor on the UI thread (prevents error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views)
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I can swap out the cursor in my adapter from any other class =)

Comment: I would also suggest you to read this http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html

Comment: **don't** create a static reference to a `Context` object, it may cause a memory leak.